# 3 levels of child to parent SOQL query from a custom child to parent

Tags: soql

```
Select Name, Contact.Name ,Pension_Contract__c.Contact.Account.Name From Pension_Contract__c Where Signing_Status__c = 'Completed'
```

Why do I get this error ?

Is this the wrong way of querying from child to parent ?

> Select Name, Contact.Name
> ,Pension_Contract__c.Contact__r.Account__r.Name
> ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:14 Didn't understand relationship 'Contact' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom
> relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom
> relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for
> the appropriate names.

Comment: Is `Pension_Contract__c` your relationship field from `Pension_Contract__c` to `Contact`? If so, the 2nd field in your SOQL needs to traverse through the custom relationship.

Comment: Yes, Pension_Contract__c is the child of Contact*Master).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to return a custom field value from parent object, simply reference the Lookup/Master-Detail field's API name and change the `__c` to `__r`.

If your lookup field API name is `Contact__c`, then use `Contact__r.somefield`

For example:

```sql
Select Name, Contact__r.Name , Contact__r.Account.Name
From Pension_Contract__c 
Where Signing_Status__c = 'Completed'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong relationship. Please remove `Pension_Contract__c.` from the relationship as mentioned below:-

```
Select Name, Contact.Name , Contact.Account.Name From Pension_Contract__c Where Signing_Status__c = 'Completed'
```

Refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm to understand the child & parent relationship of custom objects.